# Lighttpd prevent SSL error on removed subdomain

Tags: lighttpd

I have this problem and not sure what to do about.

I had a subdomain configured which now is not valid any more. The subdomain was used for OwnCloud so quite a few sync clients where set up against it. Since the service is terminated and I'm not hosting Owncloud any longer I have removed the subdomain and all traces of it on the server.

My problem is that I'm still getting hit by old clients (left on who knows who computers/tablets/etc) on the subdomain address. This normally won't be a problem, but the subdomain was set up with SSL enabled and all the clients are trying to get data from https://cloudstorage.example.com which results in a flood of errors in lighttpd error log.

I have tried to set force traffic redirection to non-ssl domain but it doesn't really work.

This is how I tried to force the the redirection in the lighttpd.conf:

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "https" {
 $HTTP["host"] =~ "^(cloudstorage)\.example\.com$" {
        url.redirect = (".*" => "http://%0$0")
        }
       }
```

Any suggestions, if not maybe some workarounds to prevent my error log being flooded with errors like:

```
2017-08-21 14:01:48: (network.c.117) SSL: no certificate/private key for TLS server name cloudstorage.example.com
2017-08-21 14:01:48: (connections.c.305) SSL: 1 error:1412E0E2:SSL routines:ssl_parse_clienthello_tlsext:clienthello tlsext
2017-08-21 14:01:48: (connections.c.305) SSL: 1 error:1408A0E3:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:parse tlsext
```

The last thing I want to do is to create an SSL cert for a non-existing domain.

Comment: As soon as a client tries to connect with HTTPS you need to start with HTTPS. After a successful connection, you can redirect back to HTTP. But that makes no sense as you can leave it at HTTPS then anyway. What you are trying to achieve is not possible.

Comment: Great... So probably the solution is to get a valid SSL cert, and just generate a 404 on the domain. What bummer. Anyway if that's the case please post the comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client connects with HTTPS, the handshake must be completed before any HTTP data can be transmitted, including redirects. Otherwise any HTTPS could be intercepted *very* easily!

So if you want that HTTPS connections succeed and deliver a redirect, 404 or anything else, you need a certificate. If you do not care if the connection succeeds or not, but just want to prevent read timeouts and server errors, you can create a self-signed one.